# Global Generic PropertyEditorSupport for @PathVariable -> Domain Object

Tags: java, spring, generics, converters, propertyeditor

I'm using Spring 4 with Spring Data MongoDB and want to get rid of some boilerplate code in my controllers.

I just want to replace this:

```
@RequestMapping("{id}")
void a(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
   DomainObject do = service.getDomainObjectById(id);
   // ...
}
```

with this:

```
@RequestMapping("{id}")
void a(@PathVariable("id") DomainObject do) {
  // ...
}
```

At the moment I've got to write a pair of `PropertyEditorSupport` and `@ControllerAdvice` classes for each domain object I have:

```
@Component
public class SomeDomainObjectEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Autowired
    SomeDomainObjectService someDomainObjectService;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(someDomainObjectService.getById(new ObjectId(text)));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        SomeDomainObject value = (SomeDomainObject) getValue();
        return (value != null ? value.getId().toString() : null);
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeDomainObjectControllerAdvice {
    @Autowired
    SomeDomainObjectEditor someDomainObjectEditor;

    @InitBinder
    public void register(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(SomeDomainObject.class, someDomainObjectEditor);
    }
}
```

And I can't figure out an easy way to get this done in a generic way, because I have a lot of domain objects and all behave the same.

All my domain objects implement `BaseDocument<ID>` and thus have the `getId()` method. So basically I want something like this:

```
public class BaseDocumentPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport { ... }
```

It would also be okay (= nice) to have this working, using a `Converter<String, BaseDocument<?>>` which can be used also in other places within the Spring Framework.

My main problem is, that I can't imagine an easy way to find the corresponding `@Service` in order to fetch the domain object from DB. (I can't use the `Repository` because of access restriction for certain data).

Hopefully you have some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Consider writing and registering your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Comment: That was fast! I already thought about that, but then I would have a global instance which has to register all those `<DomainObject, Service>` tuples. That's a lot of coupling which I don't want, because it should be possible to remove/add some Maven module without rewriting code. Or am I just thinking the wrong way?

Comment: You either do that coupling in your `@Controller`, `PropertyEditor`, `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` or some Factory that returns the appropriate `@Service` to use. The dependency will have to exist somewhere.

Comment: What do you thing about: Every `@Service` will implement some interface `ICanRetrieveDomainObject<DomainObject>` with `DomainObject getById(ID id)` and then I could just scan the classpath for the corresponding Service?

Comment: The `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` gives you access to the parameter and therefore the parameter type. You can just keep a Map of `Class -> Service` and retrieve the appropriate one.

Comment: Yeah, but for this, every service has to implement some interface, else I wouldn't know which method to call in order to get the domain object from DB.

Comment: In that sense, yes, you are correct. Note that I prefer the original way you had of doing it. It's more descriptive code to me.

Comment: That's true. But this way I have to write 20 lines of code and can delete 10 lines. Sounds a bit counterproductive to me. Can you imagine (or maybe you already have written) some kind of the *original way* which produces less code? Maybe I should just use 2 abstract classes, which just get the DomainObjectClass and the ServiceClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NEWER:

If you also want proper Exception handling, you should use `DomainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar`, because `DomainClassConverter` swallows underlying exceptions...

Here we go! Just update your `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` with:

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer initializer = (ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) adapter.getWebBindingInitializer();
    initializer.setPropertyEditorRegistrar(domainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public DomainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar domainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar() {
    return new DomainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar();
}
```

(Maybe `@Bean` is unnecessary, but at least it works this way)

### NEW:

Spring Data already provides everything I need: `DomainClassConverter`

Just put

```
@Bean
public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter() {
    return new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(mvcConversionService());
}
```

in the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class and it all works out of the box!

### OLD:

My final solution was to just stay with the *one pair of classes per domain object* approach. I just built 2 abstract classes plus an interface, to minimize the effort:

**1.** PropertyEditor

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityEditor<ID extends Serializable, SERVICE extends CanGetEntityById<?, ID>> extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Autowired
    SERVICE service;

    @Autowired
    ConversionService cs;

    final Class<ID> id;

    public AbstractEntityEditor(Class<ID> id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(service.getById(cs.convert(text, id)));
    }

}
```

**2.** ControllerAdvice

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityEditorControllerAdvice<EDITOR extends PropertyEditor> {

    @Autowired
    EDITOR editor;

    final Class<?> entity;

    public AbstractEntityEditorControllerAdvice(Class<?> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void register(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(entity, editor);
    }

}
```

**3.** Service interface to retrieve an domain object

```
public interface CanGetEntityById<ENTITY, ID extends Serializable> {
    ENTITY getById(ID id) throws NotFoundException;
}
```

---

And here's a sample use case:

**1.**

```
@Component
public class UserEditor extends AbstractEntityEditor<ObjectId, UserService> {
    public UserEditor() {
        super(ObjectId.class);
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserControllerAdvice extends AbstractEntityEditorControllerAdvice<UserEditor>{
    public UserControllerAdvice() {
        super(User.class);
    }
}
```

**3.**

```
public interface UserService extends GetEntityById<User, ObjectId> { }
```

**4.**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    public User getById(ObjectId id) throws NotFoundException {
        // fetch User from repository and return
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a way to make it a bit better, but at least it works! And now it's just 5 lines of code to write `:-)`.

Comment: DomainClassPropertyEditorRegistrar is deprecated